# How to Remove # from file for the machting keyword using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a file which contains following

## # this is temp file

## # tempvalue = 0

I want to uncomment tempvalue and change value of tempvalue to 1

## # this is temp file

**tempvalue = 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
sed -i 's/# tempvalue = 0/tempvalue = 1/g' file_name
```